# Invalid columns on trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get the error invalid column media.user and tuid. Before running this i see that media.user does exist and i would think that the coalesce() as tuid would solve the tuid problem.

Why are these columns invalid?

```
CREATE TRIGGER  media_comment_trig_0  ON  media_comment   AFTER INSERT  AS  
INSERT INTO user_incoming_media_comments(recipient, comment) 
        SELECT coalesce(p.author, [media.user]) as tuid, INSERTED.id 
        FROM media
        JOIN INSERTED ON media.id = INSERTED.media
        LEFT JOIN media_comment p on p.id=INSERTED.parent
        WHERE tuid <> INSERTED.author;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USER is a reserved SQL keyword, so you'll need to write it as `[media].[user]` instead.

Also, you can't use an alias in the WHERE clause. You'll have to put the full expression back in there:

```
 WHERE coalesce(p.author, [media].[user]) <> INSERTED.author;
```

Comment: This is why reserved words make poor choices for object names! Would be nice if people would fix these as soon as they write the first query and realize oh this is reserved word!

Comment: HLGEM: The table is not only generated but the column was NOT a reserve word in sqlite (and i think mysql).

Answer (score 2):

change `[media.user]` to `[media].[user]`, the `[` and `]` cause SQL Server to think `[media.user]` is the column name, and not the table.column.

Also, you need to change `WHERE tuid <> INSERTED.author;` to `WHERE coalesce(p.author, [media].[user]) <> INSERTED.author;`.  You must repeat the COALESCE and can't use the column alias in the WHERE.

Answer (score 1):

Does the column exist in the table? COALESCE will substitute a **NULL** value not a missing column.

Also this [media.user] should be media.[user]

you also need to repeat it in your WHERE clause